# Find $a$ such that $a^2+2m+1$ is a square number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I stumbled over a number theoretic question that I cannot really approach

Imagine this: Somebody gives you an integer $m \ge 0.$ How do you find all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a^2+2m+1$ is a square number so $a^2+2m+1 = b^2$ for some integer $b$?

Comment: What happens when $a= \pm m$....?

Comment: That's a very nice way to show that a solution exists, certainly. Are you claiming that there are no more solutions? If so, consider the case that $m=4.$

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}
&a^2+2m+1 = b^2 \\
\Rightarrow& b^2-a^2=2m+1\\
\Rightarrow& (b+a)(b-a)=2m+1\\
\end{align}$$
so $$\{(a,b)|a=\frac{u-v}{2},b=\frac{u+v}{2}, uv=2m+1, u,v\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$ is the set of all solutions.

Comment: Nicely done. Worth noting, perhaps, that there is always at least one $a$ for which such a $b$ exists (at least $2$ when $m\ne 0$).

Comment: @CameronBuie let $u=2m+1,v=1$, we have $(a,b)=(m,m+1)$; when $m\neq 0$, $(a,b)=(-m,m+1)$ is also a solution.

Comment: Right. That's what I was getting at (and what Trogdor was talking about in the comment above).